# Using jQuery to iteratively add more and more divs then animate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory

I'm sure I must be breaking a fundamental rule of performance but my iterative function freezes the page after about 150 'maggots' have been added. Doing similar in Flash produces great results but ising jQuery things seem to freeze after a couple of minutes. http://www.transum.org/Software/SW/Starter_of_the_day/starter_February28.ASP
Here's the main function:

```
function MoveMaggot(n) {
if(isNaN(MagPos[n])){MagPos[n]=1}else{MagPos[n]++};
MagLeftCoord[n] += 10;
var ThisMaggot = $('#MainContainer #maggot'+n);
ThisMaggot.stop().animate({left:MagLeftCoord[n]+'px'},100,function() {  
    if(MagPos[n]%6==1){ThisMaggot.removeClass('posA').addClass('posB')};
    if(MagPos[n]%6==2){ThisMaggot.removeClass('posB').addClass('posC')};
    if(MagPos[n]%6==3){ThisMaggot.removeClass('posC').addClass('posD')};
    if(MagPos[n]%6==4){ThisMaggot.removeClass('posD').addClass('posC')};
    if(MagPos[n]%6==5){ThisMaggot.removeClass('posC').addClass('posB')};
    if(MagPos[n]%6==0){ThisMaggot.removeClass('posB').addClass('posA')};
    if(MagLeftCoord[n]>1000){
        MagPos[n]=1;
        MagLeftCoord[n]=Math.random()*1500-2000;
        ThisMaggot.css({left:MagLeftCoord[n]+'px'});
        if(NumOfMaggots<500){
            NumOfMaggots++;
            $('#MainContainer').append('<div class=maggot id=maggot'+NumOfMaggots+'></div>');
            MagLeftCoord[NumOfMaggots]=Math.random()*1500-2000;
            $('#maggot'+NumOfMaggots).css({top:(Math.random()*460)+'px',left:MagLeftCoord[NumOfMaggots]+'px'});
            MoveMaggot(NumOfMaggots);
        }
    }
    if(NumOfMaggots<500){MoveMaggot(n)};
})
```

}

Comment: The reason for this is that your browser uses a single thread for rendering UI *and* running javascript. So while your long-running JS is running, the UI becomes unresponsive. This does not happen with Flash as that is an add-in that runs on its own thread. I don't have an answer, per se, to your problem, but I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: 1.Could it be better if use an `if else` instead of `if`? 2.I think you should create a `div` and move it with `style` instead of create and append new `div` again and again inside the timer.